# prepare statement for insert in php failed in my case

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using ajax and I can't tell what the error is, but I am certain that the data has been inserted in my database. Here is what I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['category_id'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO post_items(`post_id`,`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt = bind_param('ssii',$content,$date,$user_id,$category_id);

    if($stmt->execute()) { 
        echo mysqli_insert_id($db);

    }else{
        echo "Something is wrong. Insert failed..";
    }
}
```

My old working version (with the lack of security) is shown below:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['category_id'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

/*  $result = $db->query("INSERT INTO post_items(`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (".$content."', '".$date."', '".$user_id."', '".$category_id."')");*/

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO post_items(`post_id`,`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt = bind_param('ssii',$content,$date,$user_id,$category_id);

    if($stmt->execute()) { 
        echo mysqli_insert_id($db);

    }else{
        echo "Something is wrong. Insert failed..";
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I did wrong here as it is the first time that I have worked with this material.

Comment: @RonniSkansing so how should it be?

Comment: In general I would suggest checking for errors and logging them to a file in your ajax code. Then you can watch the log file as you debug so that you're not completely in the dark.

Comment: Is `post_id` set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` by any chance? If so, take it out. Plus, your values/binds don't match.

Comment: can u correct it here for me? http://pastebin.com/BwWs4RAZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't bind the same number of parameters as value you assign...

Also, The way you are using bind_param is wrong. It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['category_id'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO post_items(`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $content);
    ...
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $category_id);

    if($stmt->execute()) { 
        echo mysqli_insert_id($db);

    }else{
        echo "Something is wrong. Insert failed..";
    }
}
```

or you could also do the following :

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['category_id'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO post_items(`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    if($stmt->execute(array($content,$date,$user_id,$category_id))) { 
        echo mysqli_insert_id($db);

    }else{
        echo "Something is wrong. Insert failed..";
    }
}
```

also just to let you know, pdo has a method to fetch the last id, so instead of
     mysqli_insert_id
you could use
     $stmt->lastInsertId()

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['category_id'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO post_items(`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $content);
    ...
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $category_id);

    if($stmt->execute()) { 
        echo $stmt->lastInsertId();

    }else{
        echo "Something is wrong. Insert failed..";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not always easy to code without testing ^^, bindParam bind the value to the X "?" it founds (where x is the first parameter of the function) and the second parameter is the value binded... look at this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I copied your code and do like this, but did not work     $stmt->bindParam(1, 'ssii');
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $content);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $date);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $category_id);

Comment: Are you sure that your table columns "post_id" is a string? Currently you are trying to put 'ssii' in the "post_id"

Comment: it's auto increment, it's an int

Comment: Change your request to the following INSERT INTO post_items(`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?) and the parameters should be $stmt->bindParam(1, $content); $stmt->bindParam(2, $date); $stmt->bindParam(3, $user_id); $stmt->bindParam(4, $category_id);

Comment: Why are you mixing up PDO and mysqli? ;-)